# Why Functional API in java does not handle checked exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, functional-interface

I saw many times that using the functional API in java is really verbose and error-prone when we have to deal with checked exceptions.

E.g: it's really convenient to write (and easier to read) code like

```java
var obj = Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(something, Other::get);
```

Indeed, it also avoids to improper multiple invokation of getters, like when you do

```java
var obj = something.get() != null ? something.get() : other.get();
//        ^^^^ first ^^^^          ^^^^ second ^^^^
```

BUT everything becomes a jungle when you have to deal with checked exceptions, and I saw sometimes this really ugly code style:

```java
try {
  Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(obj, () -> {
    try {
      return invokeMethodWhichThrows();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  });
} catch (RuntimeException r){
  Throwable cause = r.getCause();
  if(cause == null)
    throw r;
  else
    throw cause;
}
```

which only intent is to handle checked exceptions like when you write code without lambdas. Now, I know that those cases can be better expressed with the ternary operator and a variable to hold the result of `something.get()`, but that's also the case for `Objects.requireNonNullElse(a, b)`, which is there, in the `java.util` package of the JDK.

The same can be said for logging frameworks' methods which take Suppliers as parameters and evaluate them only if needed, BUT if you need to handle checked exceptions in those supplier you need to invoke them and explicitly check for the log level.

```java
if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
  LOGGER.debug("request from " + resolveIPOrThrow());
```

Some similar reasonament can be maid also for `Future`s, but let me go ahead.

My question is: why is Functional API in java not handling checked exceptions?

For example having something like a `ThrowingSupplier` interface, like the one below, can potentially fit the need of dealing with checked exceptions, guarantee type consistency and better code readability.

```java
interface ThrowingSupplier<O, T extends Exception> {
  O get() throws T;
}
```

Then we need to duplicate methods that uses Suppliers to have an overload that uses ThrowingSuppliers and throws exceptions. But we as java developers have been used to this kind of duplication (like with `Stream`, `IntStream`, `LongStream`, or methods with overloads to handle `int[]`, `char[]`, `long[]`, `byte[]`, ...), so it's nothing too strange for us.

I would really appreciate if someone who has deep knowledge of the JDK argues about why checked exceptions have been excluded from the functional API, if there was a way to incorporate them.

Comment: Regarding logging frameworks:  even before they used Suppliers, they allowed parameter placeholders in message strings, which avoided needless construction of complex log messages in most cases.  (Those placeholders are MessageFormat’s {n} in java.util.logging, `{}` in most other frameworks.)

Comment: @VGR True, but it's only the case where the "toString" method is the failable one (which is never, because `Object::toString` can't throw any checked Exception). In my example `resolveIPOrThrow()` is intended as being the failable method. Maybe I missed your point...

Comment: In the meanwhile I found something really usefull in Apache commons: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/function/Failable.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can be interpreted as 'why did those who made this decision decide it this way', which is asking: "Please summarize 5 years of serious debate - specifically what Brian Goetz and co thought about it", which is impossible, unless your name is Brian Goetz. He does not answer questions on SO as far as I know. You can go spelunking in de archives of [the lambda-dev mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.org/mailman/listinfo/lambda-dev) if you want.

One could make an informed guess, though.

## In-scope vs Beyond-scope

There are 3 transparancies that lambdas *do not* have.

1. Control flow.
2. Checked exceptions.
3. Mutable local variables.

### Control flow transparency

Take this code, as an example:

```
private Map<String, PhoneNumber> phonebook = ...;

public PhoneNumber findPhoneNumberOf(String personName) {
  phonebook.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
    if (entry.getKey().equals(personName)) return entry.getValue();
  });
  return null;
}
```

This code is silly (why not just do a `.get`, or if we must stream through the thing, why not use `.filter` and `.findFirst`, but if you look past that, it doesn't even work: You **cannot `return` the method from within that lambda**. That `return` statement returns the lambda (and thus is a compiler error, the lambda you pass to `forEach` returns `void`). You can't `continue` or `break` a loop that is outside the lambda from inside it, either.

Contrast to a for loop that can do it just fine:

```
for (var entry : phonebook.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getKey().equals(personName)) return entry.getValue();
}
return null;
```

does exactly what you think, and works fine.

### Checked exception transparency

This is the one you are complaining about. This doesn't compile:

```
public void printFiles(Path... files) throws IOException {
  Arrays.stream(files).forEach(p -> System.out.println(Files.readString(p)));
}
```

The fact that the context allows you to throw IOExceptions doesn't help: The above does not compile, because 'can throw IOExceptions' as a status doesn't 'transfer' to the inside of the lambda.

There's a theme here: Rewrite it to a normal for loop and it compiles and works precisely the way you want to. So why, exactly, can't we make lambdas work the same way?

### mutable local variables

This doesn't work:

```
int x = 0;
someList.stream().forEach(k -> x++);
System.out.println("Count: " + x);
```

You can neither modify local variables declared outside the lambda, nor even read them unless they are (effectively) `final`. Why not?

### These are all **GOOD** things.. depending on scope layering

So far it seems really stupid that lambdas aren't transparent in these 3 regards. But it turns into a good thing in a slightly different context. Imagine instead of `.stream().forEach` something a little bit different:

```
class DoubleNullException extends Exception {} // checked!

public class Example {
  private TreeSet<String> words;

  public Example() throws DoubleNullException {
    int comparisonCount = 0;
    this.words = new TreeSet<String>((a, b) -> {
      comparisonCount++;
      if (a == null && b == null) throw new DoubleNullException();
    });
    System.out.println("Comparisons performed: " + comparisonCount);
  }
}
```

Let's image the 3 transparencies did work. The above code makes use of two of them (tries to mutate `comparisonCount`, and tries to throw `DoubleNullException` from inside to outside).

**The above code makes absolutely no sense**. The compiler errors are *very much desired*. That comparator is *not going to run* until perhaps next week in a completely different thread. It runs whenever you add the second element to the set, which is a field, so who knows who is going to do that and which thread would do it. The constructor has long since ceased running - local vars are 'on the stack' and thus the local var *has disappeared*. Nevermind that the printing would always print 'comparisons made: 0' here, the statement 'comparisonCount++:' would be trying to increment a memory position that no longer holds that variable at all.

Even if we 'fix' this (the compiler realizes that a local is used in a lambda and hoists it onto heap, this is what most other languages do), the code *still* makes no sense as a concept: That print statement wouldn't print. Also, that comparator can be called from multiple threads so... do we now allow `volatile` on our local vars? Quite the can of worms! In current java, a local variable cannot possibly suffer from thread concurrency synchronization issues because it is not possible to share the *variable* (you can share the object the variable points at, not the variable itself) with another thread.

The reason you ARE allowed to mess with (effectively) final locals is because you can just make a copy, and that's what the compiler does for you. Copies are fine - if nobody changes anything.

The exception similarly doesn't work: It's the code that calls `thatSet.add(someElement)` that would get the `DoubleNullException`. The fact that somebody wrote:

```
Example ex;
try {
  ex = new Example();
} catch (DoubleNullException e) {
  throw new WrappedEx(e);
}

ex.add(null);
ex.add(null); // BOOM
```

The line with the remark (`BOOM`) would throw the DoubleNullEx. It 'breaks' the checked exception rules: That line would compile (`set.add` doesn't throw DNEx), but isn't in a context where throwing DNEx is allowed. The catch block that is in the above snippet cannot ever run.

See how it all falls apart, and nothing makes sense?

The key clue is: **What happens to the lambda**? Is it 'transported'?

For some situations, you hand a lambda straight to a method, and that method has a 'use it and lose it' mentality: That method you handed the lambda to will run it 0, 1, or many times, but the key is: It runs it right then and there and once the method you handed the lambda to returns, that lambda is **gone**. The thing you handed the lambda to did *not* store it in a field or hand it to other code that stores it in a field, nor did that method transport the lambda to another thread.

In such cases (the method is use-it-then-lose-it), the transparencies would certainly be handy and wouldn't "break" anything.

But when the method you hand the lambda to *does* transport it to a field (such as the constructor of `TreeSet` which stores the passed comparator in a field, so that future `.add` calls can call it), the transparencies break down and make no sense.

**Lambdas in java are for both** and therefore the lack of transparency (in all 3 regards) **actually makes sense**. It's just annoying when you have a use-it-then-lose-it situation.

POTENTIAL FUTURE JAVA FIX: I've championed it before but so far, it fell on mostly deaf ears. Next time I see Brian I might bring it up again. Imagine an annotation or other marker you can stick on the parameter of a method that says: "I shall use it or lose it". The compiler will then ensure you do not transport it (the only thing the compiler will let you do with that param is call `.invoke()` on it. You can't call anything else, nor can you assign it or hand it to anything else unless you hand it to a method that also marked that parameter as @UseItOrLoseIt. Then the compiler can make the transparency happen with some tactical wrapping for control flow, and for checked exception flow, just by not complaining (checked exceptions are a figment of `javac`'s imagination. The runtime does not have checked exceptions. Which is why scala, kotlin, and other runs-on-the-JVM languages can do it).

## Actually THEY CAN!

As your question ends with - you can actually write `O get() throws T`. So why do the various functional interfaces, such as `Supplier`, not do this?

Mostly because it's a pain. I'm honestly not sure why e.g. list's forEach is *not* defined as:

```
public <T extends Throwable> forEach(ThrowingConsumer<? super E, ? super T> consumer) throws T {
  for (E elem : this) consumer.consume(elem);
}
```

Which would work fine and compile (with `ThrowingConsumer` having the obvious impl). Or even that `Consumer` as we have it is declared with the `<O, T extends Exception>` part.

It's a bit of a hassle. The way lambdas 'work' is that the compiler has to infer from context what functionalinterface you are implementing which notably includes having to bind all the generics out. Adding exception binding to this mix makes it even harder. IDEs tend to get a little confused if you're in the middle of writing code in a 'throwing lambda' and start red-underlining rather a lot, and auto-complete and the like is no help, because the IDE can't be useful in that context until it knows.

Lambdas as a system were also designed to backwards compatibly replace any existing usages of the concept, such as swing's `ActionListener`. Such listeners couldn't throw either, so having the interfaces in the `java.util.function` package be similar would be more familiar and slightly more java idiomatic, possibly.

The `throws T` solution would help but isn't a panacea. It solves, to an extent, the lack of checked exception transparency, but does nothing to solve either mutable local var transparency or control flow transparency. Perhaps the conclusion is simply: The benefits of doing it are more limited than you think, the costs are higher than you think. The cost/benefit analysis says: Bad idea, so it wasn't done.

Comment: Really thanks for your great answer, the first rows of which suggest that there has been a long debate about the rationals of lambdas in java (I didn't realized that the answer to my question could have such a complex backgroud), wich is hard to summarize. Now I can imagine why. Probably, as you said, altought it was doable, it was not preferable, and making it the sandard could've had other consequences in terms of costs of maintenance, for example. Or maybe Brian Goetz was simply aiming to bring the Haskell's way to Java :-). Anyway, I'll continue with my own hand-written utility classes ;-)